# What are the sets V and ON?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Are there any known classes called "V","ON" in the subject of ordinals?
I have seen it in a few places but can't find the definition in wikipedia..
Thank you!

Comment: Are you seriously going to edit the 100 questions that you ask and remove your name? Don't you think it's a bit excessive?

Answer (score 5):

$V$ is used to denote the Von Neumann universe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe)

I think $On$ is used to denote the class of all ordinals, or equivalently the first order property of being an ordinal, i.e you have $On(\alpha) \Leftrightarrow \alpha$ is an ordinal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

$V$ is the class of all sets, it is known as the von Nuemann universe, and is canonically the notation for the universe of set theory one works with.

$\sf ON$ or $\sf Ord$ are notations for the class of all ordinals.

Neither of these classes is a set in the context of $\sf ZFC$.

Answer (score 3):

$V$ is the class of all sets, and it's classified as a proper class due to Russell's paradox.  $ON$ is the class of all ordinal numbers, and it's classified as a proper class due to Burali-Forti's paradox.